# Tools to build db2 database from scripts for build verification?

Tags: db2

I'm working on building out a db2 database from scripts for build verification purposes.

Basically we have a set of db2 scripts that were extracted quite a while ago, and we'd like to build out these scripts into a db2 database, so that we can compare against production and make sure that they match.

Any thoughts on available tools?  Or will we need to build this ourself?

thanks!
Sylvia

Update: Ideally this tool would have error trapping, logging, all that kind of stuff.  Kind of like the Red Gate tools for SQL Server, but for DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db2 comes with a command line processor.

```
db2 -tvf <filename>
```

You need to initialize your db2 environment first.